# CodeIgniter - Disallowed Key Characters via $_GET

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting echoed "Disallowed Key Characters." in my CodeIgniter application when I have a http_cookie sent via GET from a SSL relay site (a payment gateway) to my application. My question is if there's any way that I can get this http_cookie through this "_clean_input_keys" (defined in system/libraries/Input.php) method that cause this Disallowed-message and exits?

The parameter contains a **getenv("HTTP_COOKIE")** set into a hidden input and needs to be used to keep the session alive even though it will be sent to the relay site and back again.

The HTTP_COOKIE string looks like: `&HTTP_COOKIE=PHPSESSID=775572c8c3b161bc957281aa901eb09c;%20ci_session=a%3A4%3A{s%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%229666689e0c8e4f26fb38889351765304%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A14%3A%2127.0.0.1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A50%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Macintosh%3B+U%3B+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10.6%3B+da%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%221271145332%22%3B}d9b9df5d8a0b51f303cbe6bb4bbe497e`

Comment: Maybe try to have the `=` signs escaped?

Comment: Didn't fix it when I just tried. What function would you use for escaping this string?

Comment: This can also happen in HTML forms if you use strange characters like like a question mark '?' in the value of the 'name' attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) when you send it, and [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) when you grab it.